# Множественные условия выбора

Tags: excel

Есть таблица, в которой заданы определенные параметры, например:

[image]

Мне нужно, чтобы в отдельной ячейке на основании этих параметров был сделан какой-то вывод в духе "Если это красный куб 20х20 - положить в такую-то коробку", "Если это зеленый шар  - выбросить".

Функция ЕСЛИ не подходит из-за двух итоговых значений.

Answer (score 1):

Для множественного условия вы можете использовать функцию И, либо ИЛИ.

---

**Например:**

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(B1="красный"; B2="20х20");"да";"нет")
```

**Если шар красного цвета размера 20 на 20, ложим в коробку.**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B1="зеленый"; B4="пластик");"да";"нет")
```

**Если шар либо зеленый, либо из пластика, выбрасываем.**

---

Если же вы имели в виду запись в другую ячейку из функции первой, то это невозможно.

Comment: >запись в другую ячейку из функции первой, то это невозможно
Вы уверены? А как же Excel VB?

Comment: >>запись в другую ячейку из функции первой, то это невозможно
Если автор темы подразумевал что-то другое, не то, что показано в ответах, прошу уточнить задачу.

Comment: Не совсем. ЕСЛИ учитывает только два варианта - выполнение или невыполнение условий. У меня в итоге довольно много вариантов, и каждый из них должен быть в итоге сцеплен с определенной реакцией, допустим:
Красный пластиковый шар - утилизировать
Красный металлический куб - отправить на хранение
Зеленая металлическая пирамида - передать в другой отдел
И так далее. Реакции, соответственно, фиксированные. 

По факту, там должно быть не или-или, а что-то в духе - если значение этой ячейки "Красный пластиковый шар";"Утилизировать", если "Красный металлический куб" -...

Answer (score 1):

Есть понятие "*вложенные функции"*. Используя вложения функций, можно добиться многого.

Пару простых и понятных вариантов показал *Альберт Кириллов*

Формула длиннее, но при невыполнении условия следующие условия не вычисляются:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B1="красный";ЕСЛИ(B2="20x20x20";ЕСЛИ(B3="куб";"да";"нет");"нет");"нет")
```

Если текст выводить не обязательно, можно показать истинность условий:

```
=И(B1="красный";B2="20x20x20";B3="куб")
```

Истинность можно выразить числом 1 ("да") или 0 ("нет"):

```
=(B1="красный")*(B2="20*20*20")*(B3="куб")
```

Умножение условий работает как функция *И* (*1=ИСТИНА, 0=ЛОЖЬ*), сложение условий - функция *ИЛИ*:

```
=(B1="красный")+(B2="20x20x20")+(B3="куб")
```

Вариант с пользованием функции СЦЕПИТЬ (аналог - символ конкатенации - "&"):

```
=ЕСЛИ(B1&B2&B3="красный20x20x20куб";"да";"нет")
```

Можно сравнивать значения ячеек с разными наборами параметров.

Например, определяем,составят ли значения трех ячеек *B1:B3* любой из текстов, записанных в диапазоне *C1:C5* ("красный 20x20x20 куб", "зеленый большой помидор" и др.):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(C1:C5;B1&" "&B2&" "&B3);"да";"нет")

=ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСКПОЗ(B1&" "&B2&" "&B3;C1:C5;))
```

Определить, какой именно текст из заданных:

```
  =ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(C1:C5;B1&" "&B2&" "&B3);ВПР(B1&" "&B2&" "&B3;C1:C5;1;);"нет такого")
```

И последнее: сравнение не одного - нескольких диапазонов ячеек с диапазоном текстов.

Например, A1:A3, B1:B3 - два диапазона со словами, C1:C5 - диапазон с текстами.

В этом случае поможет формула массива. После ввода формулы нажать Ctrl+Shift+Enter, формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

Считаем количество совпадений:

```
=СУММ(--(A1:B1&" "&A2:B2&" "&A3:B3=C1:C5))
```

Функция СУММ "не видит" ЛОЖЬ и ИСТИНА. Бинарное отрицание преобразует логические выражения в числовые.